# Why is the child Class name returned in a parent method?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class called `Entity` which is an `abstract` super-class for many other objects I use throughout my program (for this example, the `Apple` class).

In many of the methods, I print debugging statements by printing the class name that the statement is printed from, followed by the actual debugging message.  To my surprise, however, when I call the inherited method from an instance of `Apple`, the class name of `Apple` is printed rather than the class name of `Entity` (which is where the method is actually located).

To take a related example that's easier to post a code snippet for, I have overridden `toString()` like so:

```
public abstract class Entity {

    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + (name != null ? name : super.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Because I do not further override this method in the `Apple` class, I would expect this first part of the returned String to be `Entity`, not `Apple`.  And yet it returns `Apple` (which is actually nice that it works this way for this use case, but still somewhat baffling).

I tried looking at the implementation for `Object#getClass()`, but was unable to since it is declared as a `native` method.

`public final native Class<?> getClass();`

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `getClass()`. That always returns a reference to the `Class` object associated with the *actual* execution-time type of the object, not the class for the compile-time type of the expression you call it on. So for example:

```
Object foo = "this is a string";
Class<?> clazz = foo.getClass();
```

`clazz` will refer to the class for `String`, not the class for `Object`.

You don't need to look at the *implementation* of `getClass()` - just look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29):

> The Class object that represents the runtime class of this object.

Note the "runtime" bit, as in "determined at execution time, not at compile time".

In this case I think it's *entirely* reasonable to return the execution-time class name within the result of `toString()`, but if you ever really *really* wanted the `Entity` class, you could just use `Entity.class` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes, it *is* nice that it works that way for `toString()` but was frustrating for debugging at times. :)  And it just defied my expectations of the language at first.